# Issue with the condition of delete

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I Have this Function on zend framework but i want if the rankuser not equal 0 or 3 delete else not delete so my following code :

```
$idUser = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam( 'idUser' ); 

    $user = new Admin_Model_DbTable_User();
    $rankuser=Admin_Models_UserTools::getRankByIdUser($idUser);
    //var_dump($rankuser);
    //die();

    if(($rankuser!== 0)||($rankuser!==3)){
    $nbDeleteRows = $user->delete( array ("idUser = ?" => $idUser) );
    if( $nbDeleteRows === 0)        
    {
        echo json_encode(array(
                    "response" => "false",
                    "errorMessage" => "Il y a eu une erreur lors la suppression de l'utilisateur."                      
                ));
        exit();
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array(
                    "response" => "true",
                    "message" => "Il y a eu ". $nbDeleteRows ." utilisateur(s) supprimé(s)."                        
                ));
        exit();
    } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a specific question? a part of the code that doesn't seem to fire up or something else?

Comment: so i want not do delete if $rankuser!==0 ou !==3 so i do var_dump($rankuser) there ["_data":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["rankUser"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["_cleanData":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["rankUser"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }

Comment: What datatype does `Admin_Models_UserTools::getRankByIdUser` return? Your `var_dump` output in your comment doesn't look complete, but it really doesn't look like the `int` that you're testing for.